# Google Sheets Javascript - How many users are in current session

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have made a spreadsheet that has an `onOpen()` trigger that gets the active user and then runs some code based on the users email address.  The problem I have is if someone opens the sheet while someone else is in it, the trigger code will mess up what ever the current user was working on.

I thought I read somewhere that there was a way to set new users to view only if someone was already in the file but I've been searching for hours and can't find anything.

Is there a way to find out how many people are currently in the sheet?  I would just like to add something like this to my trigger:

```
var currentusers = sheet.getActiveUsers()  //<--- Something like this exist?

if (currentusers > 1) {
//Some fancy function here
}
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is what you are looking for  (getViewers) https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getViewers() But I am not sure it will work as you want. Nevertheless, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I believe this would work the same as `getEditors()` only returning the list of users who have viewing permissions rather then the people in the current session.

Answer (score 0):

[Session#getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getActiveUser()) returns information about the current user running the script.

```
// Log the email address of the person running the script.
 var email = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
 Logger.log(email);
```

Comment: I do know how to use the getActiveuser() and Logger but without being able to tell when the user leaves the sheet I'm not sure how I could incorporate this into my script.  I could log the email address but how could I tell if they are still active when the new user enters the sheet?